# Difference between jquery object and native browser document?

Tags: jquery, object, native, document

What is the difference between a jQuery object and a native browser document object? and how would that apply to the following code?

```
<div id=”myid”> This is the div you want to select <div>

document.getElementById(“myid”)

$(“#myid”)
$(“#myid”).get(0)
```

Was wondering if someone could help me understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference is that `$(“#myid”)`returns a jQuery object

while the second `document.getElementById(“myid”)` DOM element.

To get the DOM object of a jQuery object, you can call:

```
$(“#myid”).get(0);//zero based index
```

All jQuery objects are array-like objects of zero or more elements.

Comment: Great friend. I gave thumb up and what it was not yet?